# Nested bash if/and/or statement not working going from OS X to Ubuntu

Tags: bash

This:

`while [[ $red -le 255 && $switch -eq 0 ]] || [[ $red -ge 0 && $switch -eq 1 ]]; do`

works perfectly fine under OS X, but I'm having trouble getting it to work in Ubuntu. I feel like it's something extremely basic that I'm missing, but after Googling around I'm yet to find a solution.

The error is:

`[[: not found`

Comment: what is the shell version you're using in each case?

Comment: What version of bash are you using on Ubuntu?

Comment: The above works for me on Ubuntu w/ bash 4.2.10 and on OS X w/ bash 3.2.48(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default shell and `/bin/sh` substitute on Ubuntu is `dash` which does not understand `[[`. Make sure you are running the script in `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it may not be using `bash`. If this is a script and there is no hashbang (`#!`) at the top of the file, try adding this as the first line:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
```

If it's not a script, try to find out what shell you're using:

```
echo $SHELL

# or maybe this
ps | fgrep $$
```

If it's not `bash`, run `bash` manually first and try again.

Comment: Seems like this was my problem, which is a little embarrassing, though I'm sure this is the first of many of small problems I'm going to run into.